# Using the column Created gives the right date format, but the time is not correct

Tags: sharepoint-online

In my column "Created" gives the right date format, and the correct date but the time is not correct.
I have inserted an item at **4-3-2021 16:03** but the list date gives me **4-3-2021 06:55**
How can i fix this?

Gr. Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time in **Created** field goes with the [Regional Settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-regional-settings-for-a-site-e9e189c7-16e3-45d3-a090-770be6e83c1a) in the site.

You can change the time zone accordingly via *Site Settings* > *Regional settings* > *Time Zone* (or via `_layouts/15/regionalsetng.aspx`).